# Use dependency from library module in app module

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Maybe it's a silly question, but want to collect an app's dependencies to library.(so I can easily manage all dependency's version)

app/build.gradle

```
api project(path: ':library')
```

library/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2' <- gson is just example, it can be anything.
}
```

In the above situation **Can I use Gson from MainActivity.class? It seems to not be working..**

If not, is there a way to achieve this?

I don't want to add the same dependency to both the app and library. If Gson is updated, I have to modify two positions, I hate it! :(

Comment: if you have added dependencies in library build.gradle you can access the methods in your app

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just do the reverse.

In your case, use `implementation` in app and `api` in library modules.

`implementation` uses the dependency only for current module and `api` shares the dependency with other modules which use it.

Comment: That's worked like a charm...

expect  :  api 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:0.10.7'